# Using radio buttons on a relative layout in Android

Tags: android, list, layout, button

I currently have an Android project with a relative layout.

I want to let the user set one option (out of a pretty long list). 
After looking around, I noticed the possibility of using Radio Buttons and displaying them in a Dialog, as described [here](http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2009/03/android-listactivity-and-selected-state/). 
But I read on the API that radio buttons need to be used in the linear layout.

Is there another way of letting a user select something from a list? For instance a sort of select list?

Thanks for any assistance. I have added my current layout for clarification.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFCC" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonExit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Exit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="Play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Pause" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Continue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonStop"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Continue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Continue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Ready."
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you consideer using a Spinner ?

Comment: You could easily just wrap the `RadioGroup` in a `LinearLayout`

Comment: @fiddler Spinner seems like a good idea. Let me try it... Any suggestions for good Android layout tutorials? Just looking at google and the developers site now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Spinner or a ListView.

You can find info and examples here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html